# Excel - autofit continuously in a column without having to format each time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have built a correlating list options from a picklist and want the column to auotfit without having to format to autofit each new selection. As of now every time a selection is made I have to format that cell.

Answer (score 0):

To do AutoFit once, this is done on the ribbon Home pane, Cells group, in
*Format > Autofit column width*.

To automatically AutoFit one or more columns during data entry when the user
types <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a VBA macro is required as follows.
The spreadsheet file must terminate with `.xlsm` (not `.xlsx`),
if necessary do *File > Save As* in the format of
"Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)".

- Open the `.xlsm` worksheet
- Click on the
  [Developer tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
- Click Visual Basic
- In the Microsoft Visual Basic window that opens,
  double-click on the left on `ThisWorkbook`
- On the top-right, select "Workbook" instead of "(General)" and "SheetChange"
  instead of "Open", to create two subroutines (or which `Workbook_Open`
  is not used and can be deleted)
- Enter a line inside the routine `Workbook_SheetChange` to make the routine
  look like:

  - To AutoFit all columns in the workbook:

    ```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Columns().AutoFit
    End Sub
    ```
  - To AutoFit automatically only a specific column, for example `A`,
    write the code as
    `Columns("A").AutoFit` or `Columns(1).Autofit`
  - To AutoFit automatically a range of columns write
    `Columns("A:E").AutoFit`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the spreadsheet, and then
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close the VBA editor and return to Excel.